# Does the loop define the number of request or calls

Tags: jmeter

Can someone explain to me if the loop sets the number of requests or it`s there to have an average?
If I have 100 users, ramp - up set as 0 and loop 1, does it mean that I have only 100 users and if I increase the loop to 2, does it mean that there will be 200 users doing the request?

If I needed to test with 200 users, why would I not set the users to 200? What does the loop do differently and how does it affect the result?

Comment: User is fixed value. Loop features only loops the requests.
1. 100 User , 2 Sample request in the test plan and Loop count =1 , you will get 200 requests total.
2. 100 User , 2 Sample request in the test plan and Loop count =2, you will get 400 requests total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one request (sampler) under the Thread Group:

1. With loop count 1 - 100 users will execute 1 request 1 time each, 100 requests in total
2. With loop count 2 - 100 users will execute 1 request 2 times each, 200 requests in total

With regards to setting ramp-up to `0` - it's not the best idea, it is good to increase the load **gradually**, this way you will be able to correlate increasing load with other [performance metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html), in particular with response time and number of requests per second.

More information: [JMeter Ramp-Up - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide/)

P.S. It might be easier to consider i.e. [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) which makes the process of defining the workload easier, for example here is how you can configure JMeter to start with 1 user, increase the load up to 200 users in 60 seconds, hold the load for another 60 seconds and then gradually decrease the load:

[image]

You can install Ultimate Thread Group as a part of `Custom Thread Groups` bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]